# htaccess redirecting to the wrong page when using multiple rewriterules

Tags: .htaccess

I have a `htaccess` file which looks like the following:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# no php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# only allow rewriting to paths that dont exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# example.com/username
RewriteRule ^([\w\d_\-]+)/?$ profile.php?uid=$1 [L,QSA]
# example.com/username/$tab
RewriteRule ^([\w\d_\-]+)\/([\w]+)/?$ profile.php?uid=$1&tab=$2

# example.com/listen/$id
RewriteRule ^listen\/([\w\d_\-]+)?\/?([\w\d_\-]+)?$ track.php?id=$1&secret=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The way it is *supposed* to work is to redirect any URL looking like these:

```
1. example.com/example points to profile.php?id=example
or
2. example.com/example/tab points to profile.php?id=example&tab=tab


3. example.com/listen/example points to track.php?id=example
or
4. example.com/listen/example/code points to track.php?id=example&secret=code
```

The problem is that sometimes, a link which looks like the third one will point to the profile page. However, what's weirder, is that if `example` has a dash in it, it will point to the right place. This shouldn't be happening because my regex is matching after `listen`.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your `listen/` rules should appear before other rules and moreover 2 `RewriteCond` are only being applied to next immediate `RewriteRule`.

You may use these rules to replace all of your code:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# only allow rewriting to paths that don't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# example.com/listen/$id
RewriteRule ^listen/([\w-]+)/?$ track.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# example.com/listen/$id/secret
RewriteRule ^listen/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ track.php?id=$1&secret=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# no php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# example.com/username
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?uid=$1 [L,QSA]

# example.com/username/$tab
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?uid=$1&tab=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Also note that `\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so no need to add `\d_` in character class.

Comment: Oh thanks! Also, any reason the `listen` rules should appear before everything else? and whats does `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` do?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` means *do nothing* if previous 2 conditions are success. Those conditions will succeed if request is for a file OR request is for a directory. Rule for `listen` is placed at top so that other generic rule of `^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$` doesn't not execute for something like `/listen/abcd`.

Comment: I've noticed that the line `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` will stop the rest of the script from running even if the file or directory doesn't exist (I will get a `Not Found` error when it isn't commented out in my `htaccess`). Is this a bug within your script or is something wrong with my server?

Comment: No that rule is not a bug. I am using it on few of my live websites as well. Note that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` has no `!` for negation as in your question. This rule just prevents existing files and directories to be rewritten. You may change `Options` line to `Options -Indexes -MultiViews` also

Comment: Oh! You got me there, the problem was the `!` (I completely brushed over that). Cheers for the help :)